# Nestled UpdatePanels causes full page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm having issues with nestled, custom user controls that causes full page postbacks despite being encapsulated by an UpdatePanel.

The update panel:

```
<asp:Content ID="mainContentPane" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="smNetAjax" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="pnlAssetTabView">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <custom:AssetTabView runat="server" ID="tvAddAssets" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

The AssetTabView-control:

```
<custom:TabView runat="server" ID="tvTabView" OnSelectedTabChanged="tvTabView_SelectedTabChanged" />
<custom:AssetList runat="server" ID="dalAssetList" />
```

And finally the TabView whose links causes full page postback:

```
<SelectedItemTemplate>
    <div class="tab current">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="ExtendedLinkButton1" runat="server"><span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HeaderText") %></span></asp:LinkButton>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>                                            
</SelectedItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <asp:LinkButton OnCommand="ProcessTabSelection" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' ID="ExtendedLinkButton2" runat="server" TabIndex='<%# TabIndex + Container.ItemIndex %>'><span><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HeaderText") %></span></asp:LinkButton>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>                                            
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
    </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

I'm really running out of ideas right and I'm desperate for any ideas that you might have! Thank you.

Comment: I can see only one UpdatePanel in code, where is second one? Also you need to register controls to Page.ClientScriptManager if User Control wants to hook with UpdatePanel on page.

Comment: Why do I need a second `UpdatePanel`? There is a script manager in the containing ASP.NET page.

Comment: Title said Nested UpdatePanel, so I thought u missed something. Read "Using UpdatePanel Controls in Master Pages" on  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx . Similar concept goes if UPDPnl is on page and you want behavior from child controls of user control

Comment: @hungryMind so I have to _know_ the name of the update panel that the component is placed within? Also, how  would Microsoft's approach work with link buttons in a `Repeater`?

Comment: You have option of ProxyScriptManager. You don't need name of update panel, u can iterate to control list till closest-upward update panel is found. With repeater its a different case than UserControl. U can have similar functionality with ServerControl but not UserControl

Comment: Hmm, thanks! So I put this code in the OnCommand-event handler?

Comment: NO, set them on user control's OnInit or PreLoad

Comment: Please put your suggestion as an answer, and I'll accept. When I went down the control tree until I found the first UpdatePanel, and manually invoked `Update` upon it, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have option of ProxyScriptManager. You don't need name of update panel, u can iterate to control list till closest-upward update panel is found.